# Android Location based app

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm creating an app based on locations, I need the geographic co-ordinates as well as time zones of cities as well as remote areas(and co-ordinates detected by gps). Should I have the db for that and access through webservice from my server. Or is there any in-built feature. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the users GPS location with a clas which is already provided with the android sdk. Here have a look at the [location class](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

After this if you need to store the locations you can use the [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) type DB provided by Android.

In order to get geolocation based on an address you can use Google Maps API. Check [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_exists). Also check how to integrate maps with android [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html).

Comment: should i have the list of all cities, or is it available with timezones in any built-in features, or where can i find a list with all cities, timezones and their co-ordinates? I fear I cannot miss any location. for eg: the weather channel has the name of my native town, which is much more a remote area.

Comment: I think what you want is geocoding. I have updated the answer as required. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks shadow. I think this will help. I'll come back to you after i try it. Can we get the timezones also with it?